# Regular expression to find first match of string between characters

Tags: regex, powershell

Here's the text I have:

```
Dddd, Cccccccc - abcdefgh|abcdefgh|m$P,o29L|SomeOtherText
|abcdefgh||mmmin||
Aaaa, Bbbbbbbb - y123xxyz|y123xxyz|m$P,o29L|SomeOtherText
|y123xxyz||mmmax||
```

I'd like to have returned **abcdefgh** and **y123xxyz** after the first | and before second |, and only from lines starting with word character. What will the regex expression look like ?

So far I have this expression:

```
(?<=\|)(\w+)(?=\|)
```

which return all the occurrences of word between pipe characters, on all lines, but I'd like to have only matches from lines starting with word character (\w) - lines 1 and 3. How can I add this condition to my expression ?

Comment: have you thot about using simple string operators? it looks like splitting on `|` and taking the 2nd item would work for your case.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Looking at "only from lines starting with word character", regex looks viable, too.

Comment: @RyszardCzech - yep! start with the qualifier test, then the split, and last of all - take the `[1]` item of the resulting array. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=^\w[^|]*\|)\w+(?=\|)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5Cw%5B%5E%7C%5D*%5C%7C%29%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3D%5C%7C%29&i=Dddd%2C%20Cccccccc%20-%20abcdefgh%7Cabcdefgh%7Cm%24P%2Co29L%7CSomeOtherText%0D%0A%7Cabcdefgh%7C%7Cmmmin%7C%7C%0D%0AAaaa%2C%20Bbbbbbbb%20-%20y123xxyz%7Cy123xxyz%7Cm%24P%2Co29L%7CSomeOtherText%0D%0A%7Cy123xxyz%7C%7Cmmmax%7C%7C&o=m)

**Details**

- `(?<=^\w[^|]*\|)`  - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\w` - a word char
  - `[^|]*` - zero or more chars other than a pipe char
  - `\|` - a pipe char
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?=\|)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `|` char immediately to the right of the current location.